# Use of Leaflet plugin "GeoSearch" in R

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, geocoding

I am developing a shiny application in R using Leaflet and I want to use the Leaflet plugin "GeoSearch" (https://github.com/smeijer/L.GeoSearch) in order to do address searching.

As the plugin is for Leaflet (in JS), I wonder how to make use of it in R.

Also, if anyone knows a better way to do geosearching with Leaflet in R, I am thankful for advice.

Thanks,

Jacquelin

Comment: https://github.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet.extras has Leaflet-search

Comment: Hi, thanks. I tried the Leaflet-search examples in R (search markers) and they worked, but I don't know how to do the Geocoding in R as the documentation is in JS only. I want to do something like this: http://labs.easyblog.it/maps/leaflet-search/examples/nominatim.html.

Comment: Maybe best to open an issue at github.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet.extras